# Detect a 304 redirection on an AJAX request

Tags: ajax, http-status-code-304

is there a way to detect whether an AJAX request has been redirected through a 304 response ? I tried an onreadystagechange with xhr.status==304 but got nothing. Are we only bound to 200 response codes ?

The issue was already raised on SO but I couldn't find any answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (xhr.status == 304){
    //do your code
}
```

It should 100% work

Comment: in the onreadystatechange method, right ? As stated, it is not working for me though... I get an "INVALID_STATE_ERR" instead :/

Comment: In my test I get only 200, even if I see that the browser is caching